# Regex.Match Simple array

Tags: c#, regex

Here is what I am using.

```
{"allCharacters":[{"id":"410199","name":"D4rkness1939pwnz","gender":"1","skipLevel":"1","role":"alt","level":"30","generation":"1","xp":"4420578","gold":"2593","xpNextLevel":8735843},{"id":"250004","name":"Fallen_Sir_Illuminati","gender":"0","skipLevel":"0","role":"alt","level":"1","generation":"1","xp":"0","gold":"100","xpNextLevel":3000},{"id":"402615","name":"PRO_Illuminati","gender":"0","skipLevel":"0","role":"alt","level":"1","generation":"1","xp":"0","gold":"100","xpNextLevel":3000},{"id":"146314","name":"PRO_Illuminati_BRD","gender":"1","skipLevel":"0","role":"main","level":"25","generation":"17","xp":"1897767","gold":"375492","xpNextLevel":1929158},{"id":"342584","name":"PRO_Sir_Illuminati","gender":"0","skipLevel":"0","role":"alt","level":"1","generation":"1","xp":"2000","gold":"200","xpNextLevel":3000},{"id":"252818","name":"Sir_Ashton_of_Illuminati","gender":"0","skipLevel":"0","role":"alt","level":"1","generation":"1","xp":"2000","gold":"200","xpNextLevel":3000},{"id":"336515","name":"Sir_Illuminati","gender":"0","skipLevel":"0","role":"alt","level":"1","generation":"1","xp":"0","gold":"100","xpNextLevel":3000}],"currentCharacter":0}
```

I'm trying to get the one for `PRO_Illuminati_BRD`, with the role":"main part being the most specific part of the regex match.
So basically this line specifically.

```
{"id":"146314","name":"PRO_Illuminati_BRD","gender":"1","skipLevel":"0","role":"main","level":"25","generation":"17","xp":"1897767","gold":"375492","xpNextLevel":1929158},
```

Below are all the `Regex.Match` I have used, but they all only match for D4rkness1939pwnz.

```
Match RealMain = Regex.Match(RawRes, "\"id\":\"(.*?)\",\"name\":\"(.*?)\",\"gender\":\"[0-9]\",\"skipLevel\":\"0\",\"role\":\"main\"");
```

and

```
Match RealMain = Regex.Match(RawRes, "\"id\":\"(.*?)\",\"name\":\"(.*?)\",\"gender\":\"(.*?)\",\"skipLevel\":\"0\",\"role\":\"main\"");
```

and

```
Match RealMain = Regex.Match(RawRes, "\"id\":\"(.*?)\",\"name\":\"(.*?)\",\"gender\":\"[0-9]\",\"skipLevel\":\"0\",\"role\":\"main\",\"level\":\"(.*?)\",\"generation\":\"(.*?)\",\"xp\":\"(.*?)\",\"gold\":\"(.*?)\",\"xpNextLevel\"");
```

and

```
Match RealMain = Regex.Match(RawRes, "\"id\":\"(.*?)\",\"name\":\"(.*?)\",\"gender\":\"(.*?)\",\"skipLevel\":\"0\",\"role\":\"main\",\"level\":\"(.*?)\",\"generation\":\"(.*?)\",\"xp\":\"(.*?)\",\"gold\":\"(.*?)\",\"xpNextLevel\"");
```

but they always return D4rkness1939pwnz one. :S

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: this looks like JSON to me. Why not use a JSON parser such as [JSON.NET](http://json.net)?

Comment: I just want to grab that line with regex, can you help?

Comment: I'm not good with regular expressions. I'd strongly suggest using a tool such as [Regex Tester](http://regexpal.com/) to help find the right expression.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that you only read the first Match.

To loop through all the matches you should use Matches:

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(RawRes, "\"id\":\"(.*?)\",\"name\":\"(.*?)\",\"gender\":\"[0-9]\",\"skipLevel\":\"0\",\"role\":\"main\"");
foreach(Match item in matches)
{
    if (item.Groups[2].Value == "PRO_Illuminati_BRD")
        return item;
}
```

Alternatively you should change your regex to something like this:

```
Regex.Matches(RawRes, "^.*\"id\":\"(.*?)\",\"name\":\"PRO_Illuminati_BRD\",\"gender\":\"[0-9]\",\"skipLevel\":\"0\",\"role\":\"main\"");
```

This answers your question, but I recommend that you use the JSON parser that others already have described if you need more items than just the single item.

Comment: When I use,   MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(RawRes, "\"id\":\"[0-9]{1,20}\",\"name\":\"(.*?)\",\"gender\":\"[0-9]{1}\",\"skipLevel\":\"0\",\"role\":\"main");
          the match gets all of this crap in matches[0].ToString();

Comment: "id":"410199","name":"D4rkness1939pwnz","gender":"1","skipLevel":"1","role":"alt","level":"30","generation":"1","xp":"4420578","gold":"2593","xpNextLevel":8735843},{"id":"250004","name":"Fallen_Sir_Illuminati","gender":"0","skipLevel":"0","role":"alt","level":"1","generation":"1","xp":"0","gold":"100","xpNextLevel":3000},{"id":"402615","name":"PRO_Illuminati","gender":"0","skipLevel":"0","role":"alt","level":"1","generation":"1","xp":"0","gold":"100","xpNextLevel":3000},{"id":"146314","name":"PRO_Illuminati_BRD","gender":"1","skipLevel":"0","role":"main

Comment: Instead of .*? you should use [^\"]*  E.g. "\"id\":\"([^\"]*)\",\"name\":\"([^\"]*)\",\"gender\":\"[0-9]\",\"skipLevel\":\"0\",\"role\":\"main\""

Answer (score 1):

How about using a [json parser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) instead of regex

```
string json = @"{""allCharacters"":[{""id"":""410199"",""name"":""D4rkness1939pwnz"",""gender"":""1"",""skipLevel"":""1"",""role"":""alt"",""level"":""30"",""generation"":""1"",""xp"":""4420578"",""gold"":""2593"",""xpNextLevel"":8735843},{""id"":""250004"",""name"":""Fallen_Sir_Illuminati"",""gender"":""0"",""skipLevel"":""0"",""role"":""alt"",""level"":""1"",""generation"":""1"",""xp"":""0"",""gold"":""100"",""xpNextLevel"":3000},{""id"":""402615"",""name"":""PRO_Illuminati"",""gender"":""0"",""skipLevel"":""0"",""role"":""alt"",""level"":""1"",""generation"":""1"",""xp"":""0"",""gold"":""100"",""xpNextLevel"":3000},{""id"":""146314"",""name"":""PRO_Illuminati_BRD"",""gender"":""1"",""skipLevel"":""0"",""role"":""main"",""level"":""25"",""generation"":""17"",""xp"":""1897767"",""gold"":""375492"",""xpNextLevel"":1929158},{""id"":""342584"",""name"":""PRO_Sir_Illuminati"",""gender"":""0"",""skipLevel"":""0"",""role"":""alt"",""level"":""1"",""generation"":""1"",""xp"":""2000"",""gold"":""200"",""xpNextLevel"":3000},{""id"":""252818"",""name"":""Sir_Ashton_of_Illuminati"",""gender"":""0"",""skipLevel"":""0"",""role"":""alt"",""level"":""1"",""generation"":""1"",""xp"":""2000"",""gold"":""200"",""xpNextLevel"":3000},{""id"":""336515"",""name"":""Sir_Illuminati"",""gender"":""0"",""skipLevel"":""0"",""role"":""alt"",""level"":""1"",""generation"":""1"",""xp"":""0"",""gold"":""100"",""xpNextLevel"":3000}],""currentCharacter"":0}";
var obj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Root>(json);

//var character = obj.allCharacters.First(i => i.name == "PRO_Illuminati_BRD");
var character = obj.allCharacters.First(i => i.role == "main");
```

--

```
public class Root
{
    public List<AnItem> allCharacters;
}

public class AnItem
{
    public string id;
    public string name;
    public string gender;
    public string skipLevel;
    public string role;
    public string generation;
    public string xp;
    public string gold;
    public int xpNextLevel;
}
```

Comment: What reference would I use for C# .net 4.0 windows form? Looks awesome.

Comment: @AshtonSchultz [System.Web.Script.Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)

Comment: I found it :D                                                  Namespace: System.Web.Script.Serialization
Assembly: System.Web.Extensions (in System.Web.Extensions.dll)

Comment: I am using   string json = @RawRes;
           var obj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Root>(json);
           var character = obj.allCharacters.First(i => i.role == "main");
           MessageBox.Show(character.ToString());    since the RawRes changes for different logged in users, I want to grab the name based on the role being main

Comment: I did use var character = obj.allCharacters.First(i => i.role == "main"); MessageBox.Show(character.ToString()); and it doesnt work

Comment: I also want the  string json = @RawRes; to be that, will this work dynamically?

Comment: @AshtonSchultz What is `json = @RawRes;` it doesn't mean anything to me. `json` is just your string. if you have another string, you don't need to assign to `json`. use `new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Root>(RawRes)`

Comment: @AshtonSchultz , **`it doesnt work`** ?, Altough you accepted another answer, just copy and paste above code, you will see that it actually works and it is easy to maintain if something changes in your response.

Comment: you still have the json being a static string

Comment: @AshtonSchultz Who says that? If it worked that way, it would be useless. `new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Root>(  **GetJsonStringFromSomeWhere()**  )`